# Can we change aap name or packagne name in android studio 1.5?

Tags: android

I want to know how we can change app package name in android studio 1.5..i change in gradule file but it did not work..

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.location"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Answer (score 0):

There is a question like this here: [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package/18637004#18637004)

Please check that answer.